# How can I prove a certain interval makes this statement true: f(x) < x or f(x) > x?

Tags: inequality

Say that I have a certain function, f(x). How can I prove for example, that this interval for x: (2,6) makes f(x) < x while anything below 2 or above 6 makes f(x) > x. It seems that using the MVT is a possibility but I am not sure how this applies to the latter case. Thank you!

Edit: wrong intervals sorry!

Comment: There are many ways to prove such inequalities can you give the exact example you are having problem with?

Comment: Yes, f(x) = x^2/8 + 3/2

Comment: Okay, in this case $x^2 / 8 + 3/2 > x \implies x^2 / 8 - x + 3/2 > 0$. So you have to solve this second order inequality. To solve this, you have to find the roots of polynomial $p(x)=x^2 / 8 - x + 3/2$ and check the value of $p$ on the 3 intervals determined by the roots. This would be sufficient as the polynomialis continous so it only changes sign when intersecting the x axis.

Comment: Thank you very much!